# How can I avoid "service unavailable"/"recompiling" when deploying solutions

Tags: 2010, deployment, sharepoint-foundation, solution-package, server-farm

The topic says a lot. I'm looking for a way to avoid that ugly "service unavailable" page when you deploy a solution.

Also, I would like some theory on it, as I'm not sure I understand it completely. As far as I can tell, it happens because the web-application affected (and only the affected one?) needs to recompile, so as to allow the features of the solution to become available - am I right?

What I don't know is, if there is a way to completely avoid it. In my logical mind, I'd think it would be possible if you had multiple WFEs? So Server A would handle all requests while Server B deploys and compiles the web-app, when done, server B takes the load and server A deploys and compiles.

Can anyone shed some light on this topic for me?

Also, if it simply isn't possible to avoid - is there anyway of replacing the "Service unavailable" with something prettier and more user friendly "Solution updates are in progress" or something would mean a lot more to the user. But if there are multiple causes and reasons for the service unavailable (like, if the application pool died) of course it wouldn't be very smart. But if there was a way of KNOWING the cause was solution updates, that would be great :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi  a while back we had to come up with a setup which allowed solutions to be deployed without downtime. 
You will need some infrastructure setting up

http://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2012/07/16/deploying-sharepoint-wsp-solutions-without-downtime/

Hope that helps
Simon